# Why would jquery-ui dialog's height always be set to auto?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui-dialog

Here is the dialog html:

```
<div id="login-prompt">
    Please @Html.ActionLink("Log on", "LogOn", "Account", new { returnUrl = Request.RawUrl }, null) 
    or @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", new { returnUrl = Request.RawUrl }, null)
</div>
```

Here is the dialog initialization javascript:

```
$("#login-prompt").dialog({ autoOpen: false, width: 300, height: 100, modal: false });
```

And the function that opens the dialog:

```
function ShowLoginPrompt(context, leftOffset, topOffset) {
    var position = context.position();
    var loginPrompt = $("#login-prompt");
    loginPrompt.dialog("option", "position", [position.left + leftOffset, position.top + topOffset]);
    loginPrompt.dialog("open");
}
```

Regardless of the height I set during initialization, it is always auto in the resulting html.

Comment: I think this has more to do with CSS than anything else, could you create a small http://jsfiddle.net about it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't track down the exact problem causing this but was able to correct it by stripping all custom styles and just using the default jquery dialog css file.